# Concat dynamic URLS not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, url

Our journey emails have a logo at the top that should send the user to their correct website based on country and language. For some reason, the Canadian emails are working for both English and French.

However, for some reason, the US link is not populating properly. The US is not appearing in the dynamic URL - please see screenshot.

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking setting a variable. I'm not sure how to debug. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the snippet of code:

```
SET @tenalink = Concat("http://shop.tena.", @country) 
SET @country_base_link = Concat(@tenalink, "/on/demandware.store/Sites-Tena_", @country, "-Site/", Lowercase(@language), "_", @country, "/Home-Show")
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that it’s not pulling the `@country` value - how are you setting the `@country` variable?

Comment: To debug this, Preview and Test the Email, using the DE or List declared as the entry source of your journey, then select a US user in the DE and modify your code so the variable @Country is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually updating code from Classic Content as I bring it into Content Builder. We have a field for preferred location: it's either en_US, fr_CA, or en_CA. I'm assuming now that maybe I need to set the country as a variable, and the link should be set through conditional logic.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! SFSE is not a threaded "back-and-forth" type forum; it is a Question & Answer(s) forum. These Answer spaces are "reserved" for solutions to the questioner's issue. So rather than adding information or answering questions that were asked in comments as an "Answer," instead you need to edit your original question & update it. Lots of people add something like "##### UPDATE" (without the quotes) at the bottom & then add info. "Share Edit Follow Flag" are at bottom left of all posts - just click "Edit" under your Question. Then delete this "Answer."